# WCF DataService and EntityFramework POCO Proxy

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, serialization, wcf-data-services, wcf-ria-services

I have the following code:

```
public class MyDataService : DataService< MyCustomContext >
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }
}

public class MyCustomContext
{
    public IQueryable<MyEntity> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            MyEfDbContext efDbContext = new MyEfDbContext();
            efDbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            efDbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

            var entities = efDbContext.MyEntities;

            //*** lot of other codes filtering and checking the entities here

            return entities;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is about the DynamicProxies that EF generate... The WCF can't handle discovery those proxies and i want to use lazy load in "***". It's out of question ask me to disable lazy loading and proxy from dbcontext, it will be enabled.

What i want is know if exist another way to make the DataService handle the DynamicProxies by himself if i am using Reflection Provider (MyCustomContext) and not the EF Provider (MyEfDbContext)...

Error: "The type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.MyEntity_BB149ED9827DD6216E888718F322BA36146418D1D834B040FD3A1B630341CD90' is not a complex type or an entity type."

---

I have already checked some sources to know if there are workarounds like:

- http://sanderstechnology.com/2010/the-ado-net-entity-framework-poco-objects-and-you/10142/#.UWdGp5O38SI
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/3e7e20bc-7ee2-4989-bf12-ddb228998636/ (sad!!!)

I really apreciate any help!

Comment: Did you have a look at [ProxyDataContractResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee705457%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, but that not work with DataService. Or at least i cannot found a way to make it work.